# Meaning of あるにはあります

Tags: usage, expressions

For example in [this page](http://kotobaknow.com/gosokurou), reading by context I understand the phrase `あるにはあります` in the sentence

> 足労、という言葉もあるにはありますが、「ご」を付けずに使うことはほとんどありません。

as expressing circumspection. That is, while I would translate

> 足労、という言葉はありますが、「ご」を付けずに使うことはほとんどありません。
>
> The word 足労 exists, but is hardly ever used unless ご is attached.

I would rather translate the original phrase as

> 足労、という言葉もあるにはありますが、「ご」を付けずに使うことはほとんどありません。
>
> While the word 足労 does exists, it is hardly ever used unless ご is attached.

1. Is this correct?
2. If so, how can I understand `あるにはあります` when used without a contrasting particle such as `が` or `けど`? This usage is rarer, but can be seen e.g. in [this question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11108368726):

   > Q: 皆さんは趣味ありますか？
   >
   > A: あるにはあります。(and then some examples)
3. Can this grammar be used with verbs other than `ある`? More precisely, the grammar in question is `V in 辞書形 + に(は) + V in some conjunction` where `V` is the same verb in both positions.

Comment: thesaurus.weblio.jp › 類語辞典 › 類語辞書 __

あるにはあるの言い換えや別の言い方。・  ---- 物事の有無について、ないことを否定する表現 ------ 無くはない ・ ないとは言えない ・ 無いわけではない ・ ないと言えば嘘になる ・ あるにはある ・ 有るか無いかと問われればある  .  . . .  .